# How To Check If A Specific Element Exists On An External Page With JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**What I want to do**

Using JQuery I want to check if a `div` with a specific `id` exists on a page on another website.

**Example**

From this website: `website1.com`

Check this webpage: `website2.com/page/`

For this element: `<div id="this-element">`

**What I've tried**

I've tried a bunch of different ways with .get and .ajax based on similar stackoverflow questions but am having trouble adapting the answers to work with what I need.

**Code to play with**

The below code uses a stackexchange page as an example with an element that does exist..

```
$.get('http://stackexchange.com/tour/', function(html) {
    if ($("#search")[0]){
        alert('search available'); 
    }
    else {
         alert("search is not available");
     }
});
```

**Fiddle to play with..**

https://jsfiddle.net/xzf027b5/

Comment: You can not do with if you do not have CORs because of the same origin policy. And your example code above is looking at the current document for search, not the page you requested.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll read about COR's. Above code is just for copy pasting if anybody wanted it.

Comment: The above code is wrong, it would need to be `$(html).find("#search")` or `$(html).filter("#search")` depending on the nesting

Comment: works fine for me >>> if ($("#search")[0]){
        alert('search available'); 
    }
    else {
         alert("search is not available");
     }

Comment: That is looking at the CURRENT page. `$("#search").css("background-color", "red")` not the page that was loaded.